# UWP: Defaul xaml file (view) is not being displayed as supposed to

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, scaling

In an UWP application, I am trying to display a separated view (XAML) depending on the display scaling (the layout changes once the screen is set to scale = 200 %). Best practice, using file name qualifiers,  can be found here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/tailor-resources-lang-scale-contrast

Supposedly, creating a view with the same name (MainPage.xaml)with the suffix: "Scale-200" - MainPage.Scale-200 should do the job.  And it does. A proper view is displayed when scaling is set to 200%. However, when a different scaling factor is used, a default MainPage.xaml is not called.

Any suggestions/hints?

Comment: Could you share your xaml code and how do you make page to scale 200?

Comment: I don't believe anything inside my xaml creates a problem. The app runs on a device where scaling, together with screen resolution, is predefined. Those parameters do not change during runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested locally and noticed it does not work as expected. I filed this as an [issue on the WinUI repository](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/1696), so we shall see if this is a bug or intended behavior.

However, a better solution, in this case, would probably be to use adaptive triggers in `VisualStateManager` to adapt the page appropriately to the scaling factor of your display. The reason is that scaling can change at runtime arbitrarily and in case of `scale`-specific XAML, this is evaluated only once when navigation is done (so it is more appropriate to invariant qualifiers like device family - e.g. PC stays a PC).

There is a very useful open-source library [`AdaptiveTriggerLibrary`](https://github.com/Herdo/AdaptiveTriggerLibrary), which contains a [`ScaleTrigger`](https://github.com/Herdo/AdaptiveTriggerLibrary/blob/d7774db3668615445a889f2e17f8298a279b8a5f/AdaptiveTriggerLibrary/Triggers/UserInterfaceTriggers/ScaleTrigger.cs) which does exactly this, although it is implemented as static. You can use the source code as a starting point and extend it to react to [`DisplayInformation.DpiChanged` event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.display.displayinformation.dpichanged). The repository contains samples of other dynamic triggers so you can use those as an inspiration for your implementation.

If you are afraid of loading too many elements on the page in case your layouts are significantly different, you can use the [`x:Load` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-load-attribute) and only load the layout that is actually required for the given scale.

Comment: Thanks. I have used adaptive triggers in some other cases, but the layout changes that need to be done, in this particular case, are significant. It would be way more practical to use a separate xaml, which is, actually, suggested as the best practice in the Microsoft documentation.

p.s. Scaling, in my case, will not be changed in runtime. The app is being run on a device with pre-defined screen settings.

Comment: As a workaround, you could use custom qualifier and handle it yourself, that should hopefully work